# Adding only numbers that have been "approved" excel

Tags: excel

I'm attempting to track requests for refund based on if the request was approved or not. Summing up the numbers on the request prior to approval is simple enough however I'm looking to just add up the numbers that have been approved with a "Yes". From what I can tell using `=SUMIF` would seem the most applicable to what I'm looking for.

The challenge I'm having is understanding how to write this as the spreadsheet is written Number, Approved, Number, Approved, Number, Approved, etc.

Comment: What do you mean by "Number, Approved, Number, Approved, Number, Approved, etc."? Are all your numbers in Column A and their respective Approval status in Column B? If so, try `=SUMIFS(A:A,B:B,"yes")`

Comment: I wish they were in the same column. I have numbers in column E, H, J, L, N, P, R. The column next to each number has a dropdown list with yes or no as your option. So if "yes" add those numbers.